# PDF File is not opening in Android Mobile

Tags: android, html, cordova, pdf

PDF file is not showing

```html
<html>
  <body >
   <div data-role="content">
      <object data="Telugu Calendar 2016.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="500"       height="200">
         <a href="Telugu Calendar 2016.pdf">Brochure</a>
      </object>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

in android mobile i am writing coding  below

this same Exute in browser working fine but in android mobile pdf not showing  i am new one to phonegap Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Android don't support viewing PDFs out of the box in a WebView. You gotta use some cordova plugins like [PDFViewer-Plugin](https://github.com/cyberkatze/pdfViewer) or [DocumentViewer-Plugin](https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer) to achieve this in android mobiles.

Comment: I Installed PDFVIewer -Plugin and Document Viewer _Plugin  also  still my issue not solved

Answer (score 0):

Android provides [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) class (Added in API level 21).

You can try also to implement it using [this](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library).

I hope it will help you.